# Why can't you have a "List<List<String>>" in Java?

Tags: java, list, arraylist

In Java, why doesn't the following line of code work?

```
List<List<String>> myList = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();
```

It works if I change it to

```
List<ArrayList<String>> myList = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();
```

At first, I thought maybe you can't have lists of an interface, but I can create a `List<Runnable>` just fine.

Ideas?

Comment: How about `List<List<String>> myList = new ArrayList<List<String>>();`?

Comment: @madth3 new ArrayList<List<String>>() will work only if List is a java.awt.List, not the same package then ArraList<?>

Comment: List is a class in `java.awt` and an interface in `java.util` package. So you have to take care of what is the good for you. Because of ` ArrayList`, it seems you are working with `java.util`, and `java.util.List` may be listed in your `import`. : 1°) `new  ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>()` is good if you want an `ArrayList` of `ArrayList` 2°)  `new ArrayList<List<String>>()` will compile as `java.awt.List<String>`.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Generic types are more pedantic.

`List` means `List` or any sub-type, but `<List>` means only `List`. If you want a sub-type you need to have `<? extends List>`

I suspect you can use

```
List<List<String>> myList = new ArrayList<List<String>>();
```

---

The reason you can't do this is that you can be using a reference to a reference and with an extra level of indirection you have to be careful.

```
// with one level of indirection its simple.
ArrayList alist = new ArrayList();
List list = aList; // all good
list = new LinkedList(); // alist is still good.
```

With generics you can have two level of indirection which can give you problems so they are more pedantic to avoid these issues.

```
// with two levels of indirection
List<ArrayList> alist = new ArrayList<ArrayList>();
List<List> list = (List) alist; // gives you a warning.
list.add(new LinkedList()); // adding a LinkedList into a list of ArrayList!!
System.out.println(alist.get(0)); // runtime error
```

prints

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.LinkedList
     cannot be cast to java.util.ArrayList
```

Comment: Yup, that seems to work.  Can you explain a little more about why. Thanks

Comment: You can add a `LinkedList<String>` to a `List<List<String>>`.  You cannot add a `LinkedList<String>` to an `ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>`.  Therefore, you can't create a variable of type `List<List<String>>` referring to an `ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>`, because they have different behavior.

Comment: With non generic types you can assign a `ArrayList` to a `List` as it will cast it implicitly for you. For a generic type, you cannot cast a `<ArrayList>` to a `<List>` as they are different types. You can cast `<ArrayList>` to a `<? extends List>` as ArrayList extends a List.

Comment: java.util.List is an interface (java.awt.List a class), and it is not possible to instantiated it. ArrayList is a concrete instance which implement java.util.List<E>, it is recommended to substituate it by the interface in the field, as you have done it in your first sample

Comment: The problem arises because it is possible to change the list, add object of non-conforming class. If you don't change the list, then the problem goes away. Is there a way to declare that you will not change the list?

Comment: A `List<?>` can supports `get(n)` and `remove(e)` but not `add(e)` which prevents adding an invalid reference. (unless you cast it)

Answer (score 10):

Lets start with this:

```
    ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> myList = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();
```

This is creating an ArrayList whose elements are ArrayLists.

Now suppose we could assign that to

```
    List<List<String>> myList2 = myList.
```

Now, we should be able to do this:

```
    myList2.add(new LinkedList<String>());
```

But that means we have added a LinkedList to a list whose elements are supposed to be ArrayLists.  Ooops!!!

In reality, the assignment of `myList` to `myList2` is not legal ... and that ensures that it is not possible to add the wrong kind of `List<String>` to the `ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>` object.   (No Peter, it is not *just* pedantry :-) )

Answer (score 3):

Only the top level collection can be declared as an implementing class, while the nested ones must remain interfaces until you actually create instances:

```
List<List<String>> rootList = new ArrayList<List<String>>();
```

and then when you create an element to go in, you make it an implementation:

```
List<String> nodeList = new ArrayList<String>();
rootList.add(nodeList);
```

Comment: "... the nested ones must remain interfaces until you actually create instances" This is not true. List<ArrayList<String>> x is a valid declaration and then x = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>(); does work.

Answer (score 1):

Its comparing `Type` from left(declaration) side to `Type` from right(instantiation) side. In Left, your type is `List<String>` while in right, it's `ArrayList<String>`. If complaining about the difference.

Please update the right side(instatiation) as List i.e.

```
   List<List<String>> myList = new ArrayList<List<String>>();
```

This should work fine.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question but I just wanted to share my idea.

Instead of making a List of Lists, I personally just make a List of Type[] (`List<Type[]> listArray = new ArrayList<Type[]>();`), I generate a separate List of just Type (`List<Type> list = new ArrayList<Type>();`), then `.add(list.toArray())`. This way, it's clearer and easier to read than the List of Lists syntax which is confusing.

For example, in a recent project where I had an input file where each line with only a "0" meant a new line in the original (it was an encryption algorithm):

```
String[] input = getInputContents(inFile);
List<String> currentBuffer = new ArrayList<String>();
List<String[]> buffers = new ArrayList<String[]>();

for(String line : input) {
    if(line.equals("0")) {
        buffers.add((String[])currentBuffer.toArray());
        currentBuffer = new ArrayList<String>();
    } else {
        currentBuffer.add(line);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

the `list<list<string>> l1=new list<list<string>>();` is allowed if the list contains one more list inside the list.

```
public final class CPanelXMLBuilder extends PanelXMLBuilder {

    public CPanelXMLBuilder(AuthenticatedUser pAuthenticatedUser, Map<String, Object> pSessionMap, Map<String, Object> pRequestMap, String pPanelTemplate) throws Exception {
        super(pAuthenticatedUser, pSessionMap, pRequestMap, pPanelTemplate, null);
    }

    public Map<String, Object> buildXMLDocument(List<List<String>> pDetailsList) {

        if (pDetailsList.size() == 1) {
            List<String> pCustomerDetail = pDetailsList.get(0);
            xmlDocument.getRootElement().getChild("E_SHOW1").setText(pCustomerDetail.get(0));
            xmlDocument.getRootElement().getChild("E_SHOW2").setText(pCustomerDetail.get(1));
            xmlDocument.getRootElement().getChild("E_SHOW3").setText(pCustomerDetail.get(2));
            xmlDocument.getRootElement().getChild("E_SHOW4").setText(pCustomerDetail.get(3));
            xmlDocument.getRootElement().getChild("E_SHOW5").setText(pCustomerDetail.get(4));
            xmlDocument.getRootElement().getChild("ServerTimestamp").setText(pCustomerDetail.get(5).substring(0, 19));
        } else {
            xmlDocument.getRootElement().getChild("AlertType").setText("INFO");
            xmlDocument.getRootElement().getChild("Alert").setText("There is no matching record.");
        }

        requestMap.put(RequestMapKeys.XML_DOCUMENT, xmlDocument);

        return requestMap;
    }

}
```