# While implementing HashMap: type mismatch when trying to program to interface

Tags: java, arraylist

I am trying to implement my own version of HashMap. FDor storing the items I would like to use an ArrayList of LinkedLists and for that I am taking "program to interface" approach. So the items type is `List <List<MyEntry<k,v>>>`

but

I wanna instantiate it by `ArrayList< LinkedList< MyEntry< k,v>>>()`

what is wrong with my code that I get compilation error

Type mismatch: cannot convert from `ArrayList< LinkedList< MyHashMap1< k,v>.MyEntry<k,v>>>` to `List<List<MyHashMap1<k,v>.MyEntry<k,v>>>`

My question is

If I change the type to `List< LinkedList< MyEntry< k, v>>>`
It works but `List< LinkedList< MyEntry< k, v>>>` is not %100 interface, LInkedList is not an interface

```
package maps;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.LinkedList;
public class MyHashMap1<k,v> {
    //Type mismatch: cannot convert from ArrayList<LinkedList<MyHashMap1<k,v>.MyEntry<k,v>>> to List<List<MyHashMap1<k,v>.MyEntry<k,v>>>
    List <List<MyEntry<k,v>>> items = new ArrayList<LinkedList<MyEntry<k,v>>>(); 
    public class MyEntry<a,b>{
        a key;
        b value;

        public MyEntry(a key,b value){
            this.key = key;
            this.value = value;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You didn't import the `LinkedList` class.

Comment: So did you import LinkedList?

Comment: Also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12861726/why-cant-you-have-a-list-of-lists-in-java

Comment: That's not the issue. Teh issue is that If I change the type of items to List<LinkedList<MyEntry<k, v>>> it works. but is List<LinkedList<MyEntry<k, v>>> an interface?

Comment: Guys I updated my question ( added import java.util.LinkedList;
) sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try this one

```
List<LinkedList<MyEntry<k,v>>> items = new ArrayList<LinkedList<MyEntry<k,v>>>();
```

or try this one if `ArrayList` can accept any type of `List`

```
List<List<MyEntry<k,v>>> items = new ArrayList<List<MyEntry<k,v>>>();
```

**Always code to interface rather than concrete class.**

Comment: About 1st solution: is List<LinkedList<MyEntry<k, v>>> an interface?

Comment: `List` is an interface.

Comment: I meant the whole thing (List<LinkedList<MyEntry<k, v>>> ) is an interface?

Comment: `List<List<MyEntry<k, v>>>` is 100% an interface if `MyEntry` is also an interface.

Comment: type information is lost at run-time hence there is no meaning of how you are defining the type information. here `List` is `interface` no matter how it is parametrized.

Comment: yes `List<LinkedList<MyEntry<k, v>>>` is an interface.

Comment: @Cgraphics what about my second option?