# I never figure out the correct way to create an 2D ArrayList

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

```
List<ArrayList<Planet>> NAME = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Planet>>(N);
List<List<Planet>> NAME = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Planet>>(N);
ArrayList<ArrayList<Planet>> NAME = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Planet>>(N);
```

I can't tell what's the difference of these three expressions. I realized later that maybe List is for declaration because its an interface while `ArrayList` could be used for initiation, as it is a class. I took the first syntax in my project and find

> found   : java.util.ArrayList>
>
> required: java.util.ArrayList>
>
> `List<List<Planet>> Name = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Planet>>(N);`

I have added at the header.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
```

In another place, while I am adding `Planet` Object into the `ArrayList`:

```
for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < N; j++) {
                if (i == j) continue;
                NAME[i].add(planets[j]);
            }
        }
```

The compiler reports,

> array required, but java.util.ArrayList> found
>
> ```
>           planetsForNetForceSetting[i].add(planets[j]);
> ```

Could anybody tell me the reason for this?

Comment: The message is pretty clear array required, but java.util.ArrayList> found. 
To access members of list use get(i) method instead of [i] syntaх

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First `List<T>` is a java interface parametrized by type `T`. `ArrayList<T>` is specific implementation of interface `List<T>`. So you may assign `List<Integer> list =  new ArrayList<Integer>();` This way variable `list` will have type `List<Integer>` which will hide specific implementation `ArrayList<T>`.

Then following lines:

```
List<ArrayList<Planet>> planetsList = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Planet>>();
```

creates variable `planetsList` of type `List<ArrayList<Planet>>` which is list of array lists. Where actual outer lists implementation is `ArrayList<ArrayList<Planet>>`.

```
List<List<Planet>> planetsList2 = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Planet>>();
```

Will not compile, since you cannot assign `ArrayList<ArrayList<Planet>>` to `List<List<Planet>>` Refer to this question to more deep explanation why [Why can't you have a "List<List<String>>" in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12861726/why-cant-you-have-a-list-of-lists-in-java)

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<Planet>> planetsList3 = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Planet>>();
```

Will create variable `planetsList3` with type `ArrayList<ArrayList<Planet>>`.

You need to import both `java.util.List` and `java.util.ArrayList`types since you are directly referencing them in your code.

And finally. You cannot assign item to list's index by array indexing syntax `items[index]=item;` since `List<ItemType> items;` is an interface not an array. These are totally different things in java.

Answer (score 3):

You are trying to retrieve data from given position of a `List` like an `Array` here: `NAME[i].add(planets[j]);`, what cannot be done.

To get data from an [`ArrayList`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) you must use [`get(int)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#get(int)) method. In thi way: `NAME.get(i)` instead `NAME[i]`.

Then, your method must be

```
for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < N; j++) {
            if (i == j) continue;
            NAME.get(i).add(planets[j]);
        }
    }
```

---

About difference of three expressions, and why use interface to declare `List<Object> list = new ArrayList<Object>` instead of the class itself, [look at this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9852831/polymorphism-why-use-list-list-new-arraylist-instead-of-arraylist-list-n).

Answer (score 1):

Out of your 3 expressions, in same order as you mentioned, 2nd one is the most generic one, then 1st and then 3rd.
Which means that when you use `List<Planet> listObj` then you can use `listObj` to point to any implementation of `List` interface. While when you do `ArrayList<Planet> listObj` then you can use `listObj` to point to only an object of type `ArrayList`
Whether 1 dimensional or N dimensional, this hold true.

A more generic type and preferred one would be use of `List<Object> listObj`, which means that you can use `listObj` to point to any implementation of `List` interface, ALSO you in the list you can put any object. When you use `List<Planet> listObj`  then you can only put `Planet` objects.

For your compile problem, your code is not sufficient to figure out root cause because I cannot see whats `planetsForNetForceSetting`, but just make sure that you are putting right objects in right place. Like I explained above.

Hope this helps!!!