# ArrayList<ArrayList>> is backedup by the ArrayList that is being added

Tags: java, arraylist, collections

I am creating an `ArrayList` of `ArrayList` and adding `ArrayLists` to it. But everytime I make changes to the `ArrayList`, it is being reflected in the `ArrayList<ArrayList>`.

*Example:*

```
List<List<String>> list1 = new ArrayList<>();
List<String> list2 = new ArrayList<String>();
list2.add("Cat");
list1.add(list2);  //no problem
list2.clear();
list2.add("Dog");
list1.add(list2);  //problem! the cat is replaced by two dogs this time!!
```

How do I make sure that updates to `list2` is not reflected in `list1`?

Comment: Downvoted because for me it's unclear your first sentence "But everytime I make changes to the ArrayList, it is being reflected in the ArrayList". Deepen better this sentence.

Comment: Moreover, if you're using a IDE (Eclipse or Intellij), it should give you an error at this statement `List<List<String>> list1 = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();`...

Comment: Thanks Stephen and nbro, @nbro, No it is not giving me an error for List<List<String>> list1 = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();...  Why do you think so? I'm in fact creating an ArrayList of an object, not Strings. I gave it for an example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer ... replace

```
list2.clear();
```

with

```
list2 = new ArrayList<String>();
```

The problem is happening because `list1.add(list2)` adds a reference to `list2` to `list1`.  It is NOT making a copy of the list that `list2` refers to, at any point.  So you end up adding multiple references to the same list object to `list1`.

This is a consequence of the way that Java argument passing works, and the way that the collection APIs have all been designed to work.

Answer (score 1):

What I've observed from the following equivalent but runnable program:

```
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Test1 {


    public static void main(String[] args){

        List<ArrayList<String>> list1 = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();    
        ArrayList<String> list2 = new ArrayList<String>();

        list2.add("Cat");
        System.out.println(list2);

        list1.add(list2); 
        System.out.println(list1);

        list2.clear();
        System.out.println(list2);

        list2.add("Dog");
        System.out.println(list2);

        list1.add(list2);
        System.out.println(list2);
        System.out.println(list1);

        if(list1.get(0) == list1.get(1)) {
            System.out.println("Lists at position 0 and 1 are the same");
        }

    }
}
```

it's not that "the cat is replaced by two dogs" as you wrote in a comment of your code but that, at the end, i.e. after the last statement, `list1` contains two lists, each of them containing a "Dog".

This is of course due to the fact that when you add `list2` to `list1` *the second time*, you're not adding actually a *new* list, but the same one. You probably thought that by clearing the `list2` and then adding it again would add a new list with a new item "Dog", but what you actually did was *modifying the same object and adding the same reference*. Remember that `list2` and `list1` are **references**!

What you need to do is create a new `ArrayList` object, like:

```
ArrayList<String> list3 = new ArrayList<String>();
list3.add("Dog");
list1.add(list3);
```

instead of clearing `list2` and adding it again.

Check also these articles:

1. [Why can't you have a "List<List<String>>" in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12861726/why-cant-you-have-a-list-of-lists-in-java)
2. [Working with a List of Lists in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1474954/working-with-a-list-of-lists-in-java)
3. [What are classes, references and objects?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9224517/what-is-a-class-reference-and-an-object)