# Generic types and wildcards in nested lists

Tags: java, list, generics, wildcard

I am trying to write a method that takes any List of List as a parameter - regardless of the type of the nested list.
For a method that takes a single list of any type, the wildcard type works fine (see example1). But this concept does not extends to a list of lists. As can be see in example2 the method then only accepts parameters of type `List<List<?>>` but not of a specific type such as `List<List<Integer>>`. Example3 uses a type parameter `T` and accepts `List<List<Integer>>` but no longer accepts `List<List<?>>`. Why is this and how can I write a method that accepts both `List<List<?>>` and `List<List<Integer>>`?

```
public void test()
{
    List<Integer> list1;
    List<?> list2;
    
    example1(list1); // Valid
    example1(list2); // Valid
    
    List<List<Integer>> listOfLists1;
    List<List<?>> listOfLists2;
    
    example2(listOfLists1); // Error
    example2(listOfLists2); // Valid
    
    example3(listOfLists1); // Valid
    example3(listOfLists2); // Error
}

public void example1(List<?> list) {}

public void example2(List<List<?>> listOfLists) {}

public <T> void example3(List<List<T>> listOfLists) {}
```

Comment: [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12861726/why-cant-you-have-a-listliststring-in-java) slightly goes over the issue here. Long story short, you just have to use `List<? extends List<?>>` for `example2` and likewise `List<? extends List<? extends T>>` for `example3`. Generics can be really picky.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`example2` doesn't work because `List<List<Integer>>` is not a subtype of `List<List<?>>` even though `List<Integer>` is a subtype of `List<?>`, similar to how `List<String>` is not a subtype of `List<Object>` even though `String` is a subtype of `Object`. Basically, when the type is not directly parameterized by a wildcard, the type parameter must match exactly -- `List<Integer>` and `List<?>` do not match exactly. (There is a wildcard deep inside there, but it is as part of the concrete type `List<?>`, not a wildcard at the top level.)

For it to be able to take different type parameters, it needs to have a wildcard at the top level:

```
public void example4(List<? extends List<?>> listOfLists) {}
```

Answer (score 1):

That works for me:

```
List<List<Integer>> listOfLists1;
List<List<?>> listOfLists2;

public TestKlasse() {
    init();
}

public void init(){
    listOfLists1 = new ArrayList();
    listOfLists2 = new ArrayList();
    listOfLists1.add(Arrays.asList(1,2,3,4,5));
    listOfLists2.add(Arrays.asList("a","a",2,4,"5"));
    test((Collection)listOfLists1);
    test((Collection)listOfLists2);
}

private void test(Collection<Collection<?>> list){
    list.forEach(e -> {
        System.out.println(e.toString());
    });
}
```

The result:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
[a, a, 2, 4, 5]
```

I hope that this solution fit your expectation.